# AWS EC2 : sudo: apt-get: command not found error

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have installed **Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type** second number of os in list `(AWS console)` in my instance.

It connect to putty successfully.

Now I want to install node in my server.

For that I go to /var folder. Then I run this command.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

And then I got error this.

```
## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
bash: apt-get: command not found
Error executing command, exiting
```

To fixed this I have fire follow commands.

```
1) apt-get update
2) sudo apt-get update 
3) yum update 
4) sudo yum update
```

Still I have same issue. Anyone can help me.

Comment: I don't know much about Amazon Linux 2 AMI, but it would seem that it's not based off debian or ubuntu (apt-get). So you might want to find a script to install node in yum based systems (eg. fedora, centos, rhel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install node version manager (nvm) by typing the following at the command line.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
```

Use nvm to install Node.js because nvm can install multiple versions of Node.js and allow you to switch between them.

Activate nvm by typing the following at the command line.

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Use nvm to install the version of Node.js you intend to use by typing the following at the command line.

```
nvm install 4.4.5
```

Installing Node.js also installs the Node Package Manager (npm) so you can install additional modules as needed.

Test that Node.js is installed and running correctly by typing the following at the command line.

```
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
```

This should display the following message that confirms the installed version of Node.js running.

```
Running Node.js v4.4.5
```

More Info : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to install node 8.

Comment: So may I use `nvm install 8` ?

Comment: You can change the version to 8 instead when you execute the commands

Comment: I have run your commad already. So how can I update to 8 now ?

Comment: Great. Were you able to see the installed version correctly?
You can install 8 using
`nmv install 8.0`
To use it, command is as follows 
`nvm use 8.0`

Comment: Hey I have maked that I have have to run `nvm use 8.0` everytime. So is there any command to fixed for always ?

Comment: Yes of course, `nvm alias default 8.0` you can issue this command and open a new terminal and check the npm version.

Comment: To other dev: Just make sure first set 8.0 version and then fire default set comand then it will set to new version otherwise not. :)